# bitbake error does not apply (enforce with -f)?

Tags: append, patch, yocto, bitbake

I'm adding new patch to gstreamer-plugin-bad.

I use below command to create my patch.

```
git diff A B > 0040-forenex-victor.patch
```

Then I move it to source/meta-fsl-bsp-release/imx/meta-bsp/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad

After that, I add a line in source/meta-fsl-bsp-release/imx/meta-bsp/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad_1.10.%.bbappend

```
SRC_URI_append = " \
    file://0001-gstreamer-gl.pc.in-don-t-append-GL_CFLAGS-to-CFLAGS.patch \
    file://0001-gst-plugins-bad-fix-incorrect-wayland-protocols-dir.patch \
    file://0001-mpegtsmux-Need-get-pid-when-create-streams.patch \
    file://0002-mpeg4videoparse-Need-detect-picture-coding-type-when.patch \
    file://0003-mpegvideoparse-Need-detect-picture-coding-type-when-.patch \
    file://0004-modifiy-the-videoparse-rank.patch \
    file://0005-glfilter-Lost-frame-rate-info-when-fixate-caps.patch \
    file://0006-camerabin-Add-one-property-to-set-sink-element-for-v.patch \
    file://0007-Fix-for-gl-plugin-not-built-in-wayland-backend.patch \
    file://0008-Support-fb-backend-for-gl-plugins.patch \
    file://0009-Change-wayland-default-res-to-1024x768.patch \
    file://0010-gl-wayland-fix-loop-test-hang-in-glimagesink.patch \
    file://0011-Fix-glimagesink-wayland-resize-showed-blurred-screen.patch \
    file://0012-Add-directviv-to-glimagesink-to-improve-playback-per.patch \
    file://0013-MMFMWK-6930-glplugin-Accelerate-gldownload-with.patch \
    file://0014-support-video-crop-for-glimagesink.patch \
    file://0015-Add-fps-print-in-glimagesink.patch \
    file://0016-glcolorconvert-convert-YUV-to-RGB-use-directviv.patch \
    file://0017-glwindow-work-around-for-no-frame-when-imxplayer-use.patch \
    file://0018-glcolorconvert-fix-MRT-cannot-work-in-GLES3.0.patch \
    file://0019-qmlglplugin-Add-i.mx-specific-code.patch \
    file://0020-videocompositor-Remove-output-format-alpha-check.patch \
    file://0021-Add-ion-memory-support-for-glupload.patch \
    file://0022-Add-ion-dmabuf-support-in-gldownload.patch \
    file://0023-qmlglsrc-some-enhancements-for-qmlglsrc.patch \
    file://0025-opencv-Add-video-stitching-support-based-on-Open-CV.patch \
    file://0026-player-Add-configuration-for-enabling-accurate-seeks.patch \
    file://0027-player-Add-get-track-number-media-info-API.patch \
    file://0028-Specific-patches-for-gstplayer-API.patch \
    file://0029-player-Add-overlayvideorenderer-video-sink.patch \
    file://0030-player-Add-get-video-snapshot-API.patch \
    file://0032-gstplayer-Add-gst_player_get_state-API.patch \
    file://0033-gstplayer-Add-play-stop-sync-API.patch \
    file://0035-Fix-6slevk-build-break-when-egl-is-disabled.patch \
    file://0036-gst-player-fix-gst-player-failed-to-load-external-su.patch \
    file://0037-opencv-allow-compilation-against-3.2.0.patch \
    file://0038-MMFMWK-7554-glupload-fix-memory-leak-when-use-a-GVal.patch \
    file://0039-glupload-passthrough-composition-caps-features-in-ph.patch \
    file://0040-forenex-victor.patch \
"
```

However, when I bitbake fsl-image-qt5 I got below error.

```
WARNING: /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/sources/meta-fsl-bsp-release/imx/meta-sdk/recipes-fsl/images/fsl-image-qt5.bb.do_compile is tainted from a forced run                                                                     | ETA:  0:00:09
WARNING: /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/sources/meta-fsl-bsp-release/imx/meta-    bsp/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-imx_4.9.11.bb.do_compile is tainted from a forced run
Initialising tasks: 100%         |###############################################################################        ################################################################################    #####################################| Time: 0:00:12
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
ERROR: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-1.10.4-r0 do_patch: Command Error: 'quilt --    quiltrc /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-    linux/etc/quiltrc push' exited with 0  Output:
Applying patch 0040-forenex-victor.patch
can't find file to patch at input line 5
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/avfvideosrc.m b/oriavfvideosrc.m
|index fdb7b49..4955953 100644
|--- a/avfvideosrc.m
|+++ b/oriavfvideosrc.m
--------------------------
No file to patch.  Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
Patch 0040-forenex-victor.patch does not apply (enforce with -f)
ERROR: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-1.10.4-r0 do_patch: Function failed:     patch_do_patch
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/build-wayland-q/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-mx6qdl-poky-linux-gnueabi/gstreamer1.0-    plugins-bad/1.10.4-r0/temp/log.do_patch.11145
ERROR: Task (/mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/sources/meta-fsl-bsp-release/imx/meta-bsp/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad_1.10.4.bb:do_patch) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 5943 tasks of which 5942 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /mnt/raid/forenex/yocto2.4/sources/meta-fsl-bsp-release/imx/meta-    bsp/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad_1.10.4.bb:do_patch
Summary: There were 2 WARNING messages shown.
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your steps are correct, however I doubt the way you are generating the patch. You seem to have copied the original file and made changes to original file and then diffing the two. I think an easier way would be to use quit process to generate the patch as described [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.6/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#using-a-quilt-workflow)